# Zip up alternating elements

Tags: python

Given the following:

```
list = [('[', "'Conrad Clifton'"), ('[', "'Rippa'")]
```

How would I get the list in the form

```
[('Conrad Clifton', 'Rippa')]
```

Something similar to:

```
new_list = []
for first, second in list:
    new_list.append(second)
```

And then convert the list into a tuple. Is there a way to do this with a list comprehension?

Comment: Bad idea to use 'list' as a name...

Comment: `tuple(second for first, second in list)`?

Comment: The code you've posted would yield `["'Conrad Clifton'", "'Rippa'"]`, not `[('Conrag Clifton', 'Rippa')]`. Which is it you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> tuple(second for first, second in li)
("'Conrad Clifton'", "'Rippa'")
```

And don't name your list as `list`. It's a built-in type. You should not name your variable with built-in names.

Comment: Why construct an intermediate list? Seems kind of wasteful.

Comment: @WaleedKhan. Yeah right. Forgot to remove while adding tuple to list comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

```
your_output = tuple(y for x,y in your_input)
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternate solution (python 2.x):

```
>>> x = [('[', "'Conrad Clifton'"), ('[', "'Rippa'")]
>>> zip(*x)[1]
("'Conrad Clifton'", "'Rippa'")
```

Avoid using `list` as a variable name, it shadows the built-in name.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
>>> import operator
>>> l = [('[', "'Conrad Clifton'"), ('[', "'Rippa'")]
>>> map(operator.itemgetter(1), l)
    ["'Conrad Clifton'", "'Rippa'"]
```